# Trying to get property 'name' of non-object in Laravel (View: D:\...\resources\views\home.blade.php

Tags: php, laravel

I have this little problem here where the code isn't getting the proper form of the name I guess... 
This is the place where it shows me a mistake:

```
                <div class="rank-label-container">
                    <span class="label label-default rank-label">{{$user ?? ''->name}}</span>
                </div>
```

Someone tried to convince me that my mistake is here in the create_user_table:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('avatar')->default('user.jpg');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

But I didn't find any problem in here. 
Any suggestions on how to fix it? 
And if you need something else from the code tell me please, I didn't know what else should I give you so you can help me.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This will work :  `{{$user->name ??  null }}`

Comment: It's working. Thank you! Now it's already working. Thank you very much, you are saving my skin.

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, i sure it will work
{{$user->name}} 
Or
{{$user['name']}}

Comment: In both cases it shows me that the there is Undefined variable: user  and it suggests me to turn its back form: {{ $user ?? '' }}

Comment: yes you are not return any array to view so getting undefined variable, so you fetch data from database and stored in array and return to view, then you can iterate it using foreach statement then uisng this {{$user->name}} Or {{$user['name']}} display it.

Comment: Thank you, next time will work with this because I tried it with someone else's proposal, but as I see, this won't be my first attempt to work with/for web.

Answer (score 1):

try this ..

```
{{dd($user)}}
```

if you gat property `name` 
then you can just call like this ..

```
{{$user['name']}}
```

get it as array not object

Comment: it shows me that the there is Undefined variable: user  and it suggests me to turn its back form: {{ $user ?? '' }}

Comment: thats mean you have to include the $user to the plade like if your controller is return view('your_view_name'); your have to include the use like this return view('your_view_name',compact('user')); and alost the user should be like this $user = User::find(1) or Auth::user() ect

Comment: the {{ $user ?? '' }} mean if there is no variable is user done do anything ..

Comment: Thank you, will know for the next time. That explains a lot :)